# Bash: A function-like structure that doesn't require a call?

Tags: shell-script, bash-functions

I desire some kind of data structure that looks similarly to a Bash function but isn't a function. A **named** structure to organize commands by context, that should also allow leading tabs.

This is nice when you have a file with say 20 Bash functions but have no necessity for 20 lines of function calls.

### Comparison:

Bash function:

```
x() {
    echo "x"
}
x
```

The data structure I seek:

```
context {
    echo "x"
}
```

I organize the commands in such data cell similarly to how I would organize it with a function but without parameter parenthesis `()` and without a function call.

What is the name of such structure and how would you do it?

### Notes

- The name of the structure should always come before it, in the same line, just as with a function.
- An here-document is not a solution, in this case, I desire something more minimal by means of syntax.

Comment: You mention that the structure should be named ; should you be able to later refer to that structure by its name? Or would a plain comment for instance be enough?

Comment: This shouldn't be referred by the name from anywhere.

Comment: The name should come before the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a *compound command* and the syntax is

```
{ compound-list; }
```

(this is an *example* of a compound command, other things like `for` loops etc. are also compound commands)

For example:

```
{
    echo 'hello'
    echo 'world'
}
```

The `;` is only needed if there's no newline before the final `}`:

```
{ echo 'hello'; echo 'world'; }
```

The commands in the `{ ...; }` construct are executed in the *current* environment, just as for a function.

More information about this is available in [the POSIX standard's description of compound commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04).

There is no reason (or possibility) to name these sections as naming such a section is more or less equivalent to creating a shell function anyway. Naming a compound command would furthermore only be necessary if it's to be referred to later, which is what functions are used for.

Comments may obviously be used:

```
# my hello world thing
{
    echo 'hello'; echo 'world'
}
```

---

In a similar manner, a subshell may be had with

```
(
    echo 'hello'
    echo 'world'
)
```

This executes in a child environment to the current shell, and changes to variables etc. will *not* be reflected in the current shell.

The general syntax is

```
( compound-list )
```

Here, there is no need for a final `;` before `)`.

---

As a curiosity, shell functions may use `(...)` in place of `{...;}` to execute their code in a local environment:

```
helloworld () (
    echo 'hello'
    echo 'world'
)
```

This may be useful to know if one is writing a function in a `sh` language that does not support local variables (`local` or `typeset` in `bash`) and that does not need to modify the script's environment.

Answer (score 1):

Are comments enough?

You could use them as follows to regroup commands and provide a name to those groups, and nothing forbids you from using indentation :

```
#context1
    echo "I'm in context1"
#end of context1

#context2
    echo "I'm in context2"
#end of context2
```

You could also regroup commands with `{...}`, which wouldn't have any other effect in this context AFAIK :

```
#context1
{
    echo "I'm in context1"
}
#end of context1


{ #context2
    echo "I'm in context2"
} #end of context2
```

If you want in addition to associate these contexts with a local scope, you could use subshells :

```
#context1
(
    context="context1"
    echo "I'm in $context"
)
#end of context1

( #context2
    echo "I'm in $context" #context is undefined there
    context=context2
    echo "I'm in $context"
) #end of context2
```

[try it here](https://ideone.com/mf8S0r)